# IOS UIButton Target doesnot working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

here is my code

```
   for (NSString *message in self.messages) {
    label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setTitle:message forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //label.titleLabel.text = message;
    label.tag = i;
    [label addTarget:self action:@selector(gototest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

            CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.titleLabel.font];
    CGFloat width = size.width + kPADDING;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self addSubview:label];

    i++;

    xPos += width;
   }

-(void)gototest:(UIButton*)sender
{
int tag = sender.tag;
NSLog(@"test %@",@"ccc ");
}
```

So nothing happen when I click on the buttons.

Note that the class is extend from UIScrollView and also I have to create a marquee with different news and when I click in any of this news, I have to go to the detail of the chosen new.

Please help me

Comment: `UIControlEventTouchDown` should be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Comment: is your button getting the touch events? if your button doesn't lie in the superview's frame properly, the touch events can be missed. Also, did you apply any gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIControlEventTouchDown` should not be the problem, it works too. Can you try the following

```
label = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

instead of

```
label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Too I suspect the following line too

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, width, self.frame.size.height);
```

the frame you are setting confirm it is correct, in normal usage it may appear that your UIButton is visible, but it may not. Try put

```
label.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

and check, if your UIButton is actually visible, that might be the reason your action not working..

**UPDATE**

Ok, As per my understanding, as you are saying, you are trying to create `Marquee`, and the original implementation had `UILabel` and you are trying to change that to `UIButton`. Let change few things as the code below,

```
for (NSString *message in self.messages) {
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.text = message;
    label.tag = i;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gototest:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;



    CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.font];
    CGFloat width = size.width + kPADDING;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self addSubview:label];

    i++;

    xPos += width;
}
```

And your action

```
-(void)gototest:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
   int tag = sender.view.tag;
   NSLog(@"test %@",@"ccc ");
}
```

Comment: @Houssam Can you add `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));` in the end and tell me the output ?

Comment: {{16, 0}, {84, 30}}  {{100, 0}, {111, 30}} {{211, 0}, {90, 30}} {{301, 0}, {102, 30}}  {{403, 0}, {85, 30}} {{488, 0}, {84, 30}}

Comment: plz can you give me your email i need to send to u the project

Comment: or give me ur name on Skype

Answer (score 0):

Use touch event "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" intends of "UIControlEventTouchDown".

Comment: @Houssam the problem is not with your code i used your same code but for single button its working fine.

            UIButton *label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [label setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            //label.titleLabel.text = message;
            label.tag = 0;
            [label addTarget:self action:@selector(gototest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            
            label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,50);
            [self addSubview:label];

Comment: maybe the problem is in the marquee, I dont know

Answer (score 0):

It will works fine :

> [label addTarget:self action:@selector(grottiest:)
>   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Edit :

```
  label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, 100, 100)];
  [label setTitle:message forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  //label.titleLabel.text = message;
  label.tag = i;
  [label addTarget:self action:@selector(gototest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self addSubview:label];
```

Comment: sry man , it didnt work, can you give me an example with marquee but clickable

Comment: I think the problem is this line :   CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.titleLabel.font]; Can you test my edit ?

Comment: Or just control the frame of buttons when they are displayed :)

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is working fine with single button. The problem is somewhere else..**

```
    UIButton *label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //label.titleLabel.text = message;
    label.tag = 0;
    [label addTarget:self action:@selector(gototest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,50);
    [self addSubview:label];
```

Comment: the problem area can be CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.titleLabel.font];

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

with

```
UIButton *label = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: perhaps some more detail would be nice to explain the reason. see [answer]